# Google Voice AIY Login accounts

Tags: raspberry-pi3, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-voice, google-aiy

do you think it is possible to implement a feature like the following one [Google Home Setup](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7029485?hl=en&ref_topic=7196250) in order to let the voice AIY kit to be discoverable in a wifi network and have a person logging in to it?

Comment: Yeah you could do that with AndroidThings

Comment: If I'm not wrong it would allow a Google Home app to discover my AIY voice kit over wifi and to login into it my google account

Answer (score 0):

Google Home app support for the AIY voice kit is not available yet, but it is on the [roadmap](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/release-notes#coming_soon).